# Send JSON Array to MySql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, json, post

I need to send array to my mysql database.

I've created a JSON array and dont know how to post it to php to transfer to db.

```
$( function () {
        $( '#orderForm' ).on( 'submit', function ( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var myData = [],
                keys = ['item', 'qty', 'price'],
                url = this.action;

            $( '#orderTable' ).find( 'tr:gt(0)' ).each( function ( i, row ){
                    var oRow = {};

                    $( row ).find( 'td' ).each( function ( j, cell ) {
                            oRow[keys[j]] = $( cell ).text();
                    } );

                    myData.push( oRow );
            } );

            console.log( myData );
            console.log( JSON.stringify( myData ) );
        } );
    } );
```

I need to post it `item->item`, `qty->qty`, `price->price` to the db.

I've tried :

```
$.ajax( {
    url: 'tc_menu',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify( myData ),
    success: function ( data ) {
        console.log( "success:", data );
    },
    failure: function ( errMsg ) {
        console.error( "error:", errMsg );
    }
} );
```

Data stores whole page, but not (*stringified myData*). And I still cant get it at php code by ***$_POST*** and ***json_decode***
Data stores whole page, but not `stringified myData` and I can't get it at php code by `$_POST` and `json_decode`

php code

```
`if(isset($_POST['submitted_m'])){
$myData = serialize($_POST['data']);
$sqli = "INSERT INTO tc_cafe_orders SET item='".$myData."' ";
if (mysqli_query($db, $sqli)) {
$msg = "New Order added!";
echo "<script>
alert(\"$msg\");
window.location.replace('tc_menu.php');
</script>";}
else {echo "Error:".$sql."<br>".mysqli_error($db);}}`
```

Comment: Small explanation of problem !!! Need more.

Comment: You have a lot of doubled lines of code. Please correct. And add details about `console.log( JSON.stringify( myData ) );` and `json_decode($_POST['data'])`

Comment: @Anton corrected, thank You! `console.log(JSON.stringify( myData ) );` outputs to console the result of transferring data from table to JSON. `json_decode($_POST['data'])` decodes the data to string so it can be posted to mysql table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one for js

```
$(function () {
        $('#orderForm').on( 'submit', function ( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var myData = [],
                keys = ['item', 'qty', 'price'],
                url = this.action;

            $( '#orderTable' ).find( 'tr:gt(0)' ).each( function ( i, row ){
                    var oRow = {};
                    $( row ).find( 'td' ).each( function ( j, cell ) {
                            oRow[keys[j]] = $( cell ).text();
                    } );
                    myData.push( oRow );
            } );

            console.log( myData );
            console.log( JSON.stringify( myData ) );
            data_to_server = JSON.stringify(myData);
        });
        $.post("*your_php_file*", {
            data: data_to_server;
        }).done(function (data_returned) {
            // any your code
        });         
});
```

And seems you have mismatch in PHP code - trying to `serialize()` instead of `json_decode()`

Answer (score -1):

Remove nested click event and closure.
e.g.

```
$( '#orderForm' ).on( 'submit', function ( event ) {
    $( '#orderForm' ).on( 'submit', function ( event ) {

    } );
} );
```

Than try again.
And your MySQL insert statement in php

```
$sqli = "INSERT INTO tc_cafe_orders SET item='".$myData."' ";
```

is not ok.
Learn more about MySQL insert statement here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Not like that. Read my full explanation. Than you realize that, here I'm just explain him, the MySQL insert statement was wrong. However I'm not MySQL expert.